# MySQL DB driver for clojure korma

Tags: mysql, clojure, korma

In the documentation for the korma database library for clojure, it says this:

;;You'll also need the JDBC driver for your database. These are easy to find if 
;;you search for "my-db jdbc driver maven". Here's an example for postgres:
[postgresql "9.0-801.jdbc4"]

Maybe I'm just not getting how to read pages about Maven (I have no Java experience), but what is the JDBC driver for mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maven "coordinates" for the mysql drivers are:

```
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.6</version>
```

Which translated to lein are:

```
[mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.6"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've surmised, Korma/Closure uses Java JDBC, and JDBC requires a different JDBC driver for each underlying database.

The JDBC driver for MySQL can be downloaded here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/